# Is it safe to use a third-party program to dim the screen brightness below minimum?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, brightness, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba laptop but even when I put brightness to minimum it's too bright for me.

I download a third-party program called "Pangolin screen brightness" which allows to dim screen brightness below the minimum

Is it bad for my laptop since it normally can't go under the minimum brightness? Is it risky to make this and will it eventually break some component?

Comment: The program isn't doing anything the device can't handle

Comment: well I mean the brightness cant normally go under minimum... so why toshiba didnt add the feature to dim more the screen if its actually possible?

Comment: The simplest explaination....."They didn't want to." outside of that explanation we would only be guessing.  As I said if the hardware didn't support it, then, it wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the simplest method of dimming your screen is to overlay a dark layer on your screen and set the alpha, temperature and contrast.

I don't think they will spend so much time and risk to alter the state of those hardware stuff.

No proof though =p.